# Timing execution and loading in Silverlight

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, testing, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to determine some testing strategies for a Silverlight application of ours.
What I'd like to determine is the total time it takes for a grid to load and show data in the client. I've tried to put a timer round assigning the itemsource, but I need to know how long it takes the browser is finish loading the data into the grid.
Is this at all possible? If so, in what direction do I've to search?

Comment: I dont think you can measure how fast is binding done, but you can first show the grid without data and then let other thread download/prepare data into colection which will be bound to grid and this can be visible on some progressbar. Once collection is ready, assigning itemsource is just changing pointer it doesnt do any real work, converters on rows etc are working after the collection is bound.

Answer (score 0):

This might help an article on MSDN "Loaded event timing in Silverlight"

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/10/24/loaded-event-timing-in-silverlight.aspx

I think the main idea is to make use of the LayoutUpdated event. Since the event hangs off the FrameworkElement object I guess you could add a handler to all controls and effectively profiler all the framework elements of your Silverlight app. Something similar to the MVC Mini Profiler (SO uses/created this). http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

I would certainly explore the LayoutUpdated event further.